# How to pass command line argument values of an exe through loadrunner

Tags: loadrunner

I have written action function which calls the exe in loadrunner. When i call that exe through cmd it will ask me to enter username and password. How can i pass values of arguments(username & password) through loadrunner.
Action()

```
{
 int res;
 res = system("\\mucsdn32\\ProdConfSupport\\Rajeev\\Release\\TestProject.exe 
 ce CE");
 return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not related to LoadRunner really.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_system.htm

Answer (score 0):

Better question.  What are the command line arguments for your testproject.exe which will then allow you to pass a username and password?  The use of LoadRunner does not change the software logic of your underlying application that you are calling.